# Regexp php html

Tags: php, html, regex

Here is a part from my html string.

```
<span class="price">£ 343</span>
// Some html code
<span class="price" id="old-price-22898">£ 343</span>
</p><p class="special-price">
<span class="price" id="product-price-22898"> £ 274</span>
```

What I want is to get all the prices.

So I tried this regexp :

```
<span class=\"price\"(.*)>(.*)<\/span>
```

which makes sense to me, but I only get the price between `<span class="price">` and not the prices between the `<span>` with ids.

Any help ?

Comment: Better not parse HTML with regexps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: You should work out better question titles. Just throwing a few tags into the title won't be helpful for further use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below regex   would capture the id's and prices in `<span class="price">`
 tag and `<span>` tag.

```
<span class=\".*?(?:(id=[^>]*))?>\s*([^<]*)\s*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rM6tS5/3)

Comment: It does not give me the span without id :/

Comment: @user3812188 how about this http://regex101.com/r/rM6tS5/3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also use `DOMDocument` with `xpath`. Consider this example:

```
$html_string = '<span class="price">£ 343</span><span class="price" id="old-price-22898">£ 343</span></p><p class="special-price"><span class="price" id="product-price-22898"> £ 274</span>';
$html_string = mb_convert_encoding($html_string, 'html-entities', 'utf-8'); 
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->substituteEntities = TRUE;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$prices = array();
foreach($xpath->query('//*[@class="price"]') as $price) {
    $prices[] = $price->nodeValue;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($prices);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => £ 343
    [1] => £ 343
    [2] =>  £ 274
)
```

Comment: weird, why does this code print Â before the pound symbol on my machine? I am using Windows 7, php file is in utf8 encoding.

Comment: @user4035 i think this is an issue about encoding, check my revision

Comment: works correctly now :)

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding($html_string, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($html_string))` can be safely removed - it doesn't do anything, if the file is stored in utf-8.